# Understand ANR errors with traces.txt

Tags: java, android, trace, android-anr-dialog

I have an `anr` in my application after press a button to open an activity that creates a chart for my battery. I never use traces.txt so i don't know what i have to look at in this error:

```
----- pid 502 at 2013-12-10 14:29:15 -----
Cmd line: com.dd.batterystats

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=276

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41571ca8 self=0x414ab408
  | sysTid=502 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074172244
  | state=S schedstat=( 57059843673 4570148676 34483 ) utm=5671 stm=34 core=1
  at org.achartengine.chart.TimeChart.getXLabels(TimeChart.java:~190)
  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:314)
  at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:166)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:381)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2381)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where is the line that i have to look at? which is the error!?
EDIT: I have update the build path and now i get this error:

```
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/InputEventReceiver(15922): Exception dispatching input event.
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): Process: com.dd.batterystats, PID: 15922
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.toRealPoint(XYChart.java:877)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at org.achartengine.tools.Pan.apply(Pan.java:74)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at org.achartengine.TouchHandler.handleTouch(TouchHandler.java:119)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onTouchEvent(GraphicalView.java:300)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5655)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-10 15:30:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(15922):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: on the top you can see who is causing the anr (TimeChart.getXLabels(TimeChart.java:~190)). That is a good point to start investigating. Since is draw related, the anr I mean, if I were you I will start checking the data I am submitting to the library

Comment: The library is a jar :( do you know how achartengine library works? Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: you can download the source code also.

Comment: where can i find the source? now i get an error.. I post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to read Java stacktraces, it's easy and very useful. I have a [small blog post about this](http://fr33kk0mpu73r.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/reading-java-exception-stacktraces.html), maybe it can be useful to you.

In your second case, the error is `java.lang.NullPointerException` happening at at `org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.toRealPoint(XYChart.java:877)`. This means you have a null reference at that file and that line.

Comment: But..it's so strange.. I mean, this is the application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dd.batterystats and the chart works well... but as you can see i used a slidingmenu library and then i would update the code and implements the navigation drawer. This needs to "convert" the activities in fragments and change something in the code. Everything goes but the graph not. I use the same call to starts that activity. I don't change datas so it isn't possible is null.. And i think is strange i have to change something directly in the library. Or not?

Comment: now it works in part.. I re updated the build path with the old achartengine jar library and i don't have any error.. But the chart is empty. Seems not receive the values..i can't understand.. really

Comment: You get a null pointer exception with one version, and an empty graph with another - that suggests that you are probably passing in a null data object.  Likely the new version is smart enough to check for that and not crash, but it can't exactly draw anything.

Comment: Then you're not feeding the library methods the proper information to have it working as you like. You should read the library documentation to see how to use them and hopefully some examples.